# EC2 t4g instance AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am not able to find an AMI for the t4g type and Amazon Linux 2.
This AMI should also be optimized for ECS.

How can I find a compatible AMI for t4g, and is there one available that is not in the marketplace ?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you have chosen 64-bit (x86) architecture for the Amazon Linux 2 AMI.

> Amazon EC2 T4g instances are powered by Arm-based AWS Graviton2 processors.

It means that you need to select the ARM architecture when choosing the  Amazon Linux 2 AMI.

[image]

And after you can choose the t4g instance

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know if it's optimized for ECS ?

Comment: Here is a documentation page that you can add to your answer with more details on AMI, included ECS optimized Amazon Linux 2 : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html
Unfortunately arm64 AMI for Amazon Linux 2 is not available in all regions.

Comment: Ok. I'll check.

Comment: Thank you. I was nearly clueless.